# How do I view metadata in the first 4 bytes of a void*?

Tags: c, pointers

So I have `void *ptr` and I want to view the first 4 bytes, which is some integer.

Initially I thought I should do:

```
void *return_val = *(int *)ptr;
```

Is this right? I know how to move my pointer using sizeof after I view the metadata but I am not 100% sure on how to assign that integer in the metadata to a variable.

Comment: If you have the option to refuse `void*` and use a pointer with whatever type `ptr` is really pointing at, you could make helper macro to do the `memcpy` dbush mentions only if it's _not_ an `int*`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/fW81Tbs5e)

Comment: You mean ``int n = *(int *)ptr;``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `ptr` did not originally point to an `int` object then attempting to reinterpret the bytes in this manner is a strict aliasing violation.

The proper way to do this would be to use `memcpy` to copy the bytes into an `int`:

```
int val;
memcpy(&val, ptr, sizeof val);
```

Comment: So *ptr is actually a region of memory that I am trying to see how big it is. The first 4 bytes is an integer describing how big said block of memory is. Sorry, I should have included this in the original post

Comment: @JohnRon So, `ptr` is pointing at a `struct region { uint32_t len; unsigned char data[]; };`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes but after rereading the above code, I am pretty sure this could work

Comment: @JohnRon Yes it will, but don't use `int*` It's most likely an `uint32_t*` You could also define a `region` struct to make the code clearer - and if the `uint32_t` is actually properly aligned to start with, you don't need to `memcpy`.